# Is it possible to do a GROUP BY on Zend Lucene search results?

Tags: zend-framework, lucene

I have been looking if it is possible to do a GROUP BY filter on Zend Lucene search results similar to MySQL so that if it returns some rows that have the same specified field, it will only return it is 1 row.

Comment: Favorited - I wanted to know about this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about Zend, but in Lucene/Solr world this feature is called "field collapsing".

A few pointers:

- [Example with code](http://www.searchworkings.org/blog/-/blogs/search-result-grouping-field-collapsing-in-lucene-solr)
- [JIRA issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-1421)
- [Grouping collector](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_1/api/contrib-grouping/org/apache/lucene/search/grouping/BlockGroupingCollector.html)